# Hibernate: Fetch property on subclass

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate in a Java project to connect to the database. I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B extends A {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", nullable = false)
    private C c;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "c")
public class C {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
}
```

I am trying to write a query over A that will eagerly fetch C inside B. I tried to do:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<A> criteria = builder.createQuery(A.class);
Root<Pin> root = criteria.from(A.class);
criteria.select(root);

builder.treat(root, B.class).fetch("c", JoinType.LEFT);
```

But it won't perform the fetch. Oddly enough, I was able to do the following successfully to do a left join:

```
Join c = builder.treat(root, B.class).join("c", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If i do understand, you have a field set to be `lazy` and you want it to be eager fetched in one spefic query... The simplest way is just query normally and iterate over the result to force hibernate to fetch the nested fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field set `FetchType.LAZY` and you want it to be eager fetched in one spefic query you have two options:

**1.**
The simplest way is just query normally and iterate over the result to force hibernate to fetch the nested fields.

```
List<Class> result = session.createCriteria(persistentClass).list();
for(Class c : result)
c.getLazyField();
```

**2.** The hard way, if you have some special requirement where you must run just one query on DB level you will need to get a cursos and fecth every field MANUALLY.
As you set the field to be lazy, doesn't matter if hibernate sees it on the resultset, it will simple ignore since it was annotated to be.